# How to run a bash script in one machine from another using python?

Tags: python

From one machine, I want to SSH into another machine and run a bash script there. How to do this using Python?

I can call a local command using subprocess:

```
subprocess.call(myfile.sh)
```

I want to call myfile.sh but from another machine.

Comment: what do you mean? explain in more detail!

Comment: @theAlse  From one machine i want to ssh into a other machine and then execute a command.

Comment: @pss No Firstly i want to ssh to a machine and then use subprocess to call a command or file

Comment: @SureshSala Please have a look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform commands over ssh with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having seen your comment below:

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
#client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host_ip, username=your_username, password=your_password)
ftp = client.open_sftp()
ftp.put(myfile.sh)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(sh myfile) #or sh myfile.sh I think
print stdout
```

Comment: i want to ssh into one and then i want to use subprocess, i am using ubuntu

Comment: ok you don't need to use subprocess for that - you will need an ssh/ftp module like paramiko.