# Write a program in Python that interacts with terminal in Raspbian

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am new to programming, so I bearly have any unix experience at all. And I don't even know if that would have helped me right now.

I want to write a program that when given a input, lets say "enter". It should call for a software already installed on the Pi. Software that allows it to take pictures.

I know how to take pictures from the terminal. But I don't know how to write commands to the terminal from my own code.

Do anyone know where I can find usefull information about writing these kinds of software? I have looked but I might have missed some keywords in my googling.

Comment: _"But I don't know how to write commands to the terminal from my own code."_ Try [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: @Kevin I think by *terminal* he means the SSH client that he uses to connect to his RPi, in this case it's probably best to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3586168/2629998).

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I'll look into it. André It's not that complicated yet. But the project might become that advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

```
import os
os.system("your command line expression")
```

To run a terminal command from inside of a python program.

Answer (score 0):

This page has documentation that will help you:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

You can use **subprocess** to start other programs from your python script.