# Is there a way to manage a wifi router using Python?

Tags: python, network-programming, wifi

I am aware that we can install Openwrt on the Router. Making use of that, is there a way to access these features using python

- bandwidth allocation
- Load Balancing
- Limiting bandwidth to devices

Also , is there a package which already does this.

Comment: The answer is yes, because at bare minimum you could connect to the router via plain HTTP, and scrape the HTML for the data you need.

Comment: Or, if you can log into the router via ssh, you could use the paramiko module. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python