# Subprocess module for remote command(s)

Tags: python

I am trying to use subprocess module for executing remote command. I need to execute program called 'upgrade' that is located on remote server. Also, I need to use an argument in that call. Here is how I tried to do that:

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '15.36.77.1', './home/upgrade -u' ],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout,stderr=p.communicate(input='\n')
```

When I try to execute this command and get return code form it, I get 255, which means that command failed. Could you help me with this issuse?
No third part libraries should be used.
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558225/subprocess-remote-command-execution-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only problem is that when using `shell=True` you execute everything which you give to `subprocess.Popen` as a string. The two ways to do this with and without `shell=True` are as follows:

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])

subprocess.call("exit 1", shell=True)
```

So in your case the string which you need to give to Popen is:

```
['ssh 15.36.77.1 ./home/upgrade -u']
```

or you can remove `shell=True` to make the command:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '15.36.77.1', './home/upgrade -u' ],
                   stdin=subprocess.PIPE, subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note that using `shell=True` is not recommended as this can be a potential security hazard if asking for intput from the command line. See the example given in the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

P.S. Your English is great!

Comment: Unfortunately, I get error:"No such file or folder", althought there is file 'upgrade' located in /home. Why is that so?