# python script for enquiring the version of multiple operating systems

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python, looking to write a script which would ssh to about 1000 hosts from a jump server and  Output should contain the hostname and version of the operating system. Redhat 5.0 or 6,0 etc and I have  list of all the hosts and so the script can keep getting hostname from the hosts list. Is it possible using paramiko and platform modules ??.. I would really appreciate  if someone could give a rough frame for getting me started. or similar script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of paramiko and shell commands. See

[Perform commands over ssh with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python)

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd_to_execute)
```

Here, for `cmd_to_execute` you can use 'hostname':

http://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname

and to find the Redhat version

```
$cat /etc/redhat-release
```

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88644/how-to-check-os-and-version-using-a-linux-command

Comment: thank you for the reply, I have done all of the above already. The challenge I am facing is, how do I append each server's output  to my jump server's log file. SSH is not possible because we have only way we login to any server is via JUMP server for security measures not the otherway around. How do i gather the output of various servers ?

Comment: I can still see the output from the script on my CLI after the execution. Is there anyway to redirect the output to log file instead of displaying on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The `socket` and `platform` can do this.

```
import socket
import platform

print socket.gethostname()
print platform.platform()
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I have done all of the above already. The challenge I am facing is, how do I append each server's output to my jump server's log file. SSH is not possible because we have only way we login to any server is via JUMP server for security measures not the otherway around. How do i gather the output of various servers ?