# Why does paramiko sporadically raise an exception?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

For convenience I have written a small wrapper class to login on a remote host, execute a command, end retrieve the data:

```
def MySSHClient:

    def connect(self, remoteHost, remotePort, userName, password):
        self.__s = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.__s.load_system_host_keys()
        self.__s.connect(remoteHost, remotePort, userName, password)

    def exec_command(self, command):
        bufsize = -1
        chan = self.__s.get_transport().open_session()
        chan.exec_command(command)
        stdin = chan.makefile('wb', bufsize)
        stdout = chan.makefile('r', bufsize)
        stderr = chan.makefile_stderr('r', bufsize)
        stdin.close()
        exitcode = chan.recv_exit_status()
        r = MySSHCommandResult(command, stdin, stdout, stderr, exitcode)
        chan.close()
        return r

    def close(self):
        self.__s.close()
```

This code is adapted from the original paramiko python implementation. I just added the last 5 lines.

(FYI: MySSHCommandResult reads all data from stdout and strerr during construction and stores it for further use.)

The class MySSHClient is used within a simple python program:

```
....

exitCode = 0
s = None
try:
    ....
    exitCode = 3
    s = MySSHClient()
    s.connect(host, port, login, password)
    exitCode = 4
    result = s.exec_command(myCommand)
    exitCode = 5
    if not result.isSuccess():
        raise Exception("Failed to execute command!")
    result.dump()    # for current debugging purposes
    exitCode = 0
except:
    pass

if s is not None:
    s.close()
sys.exit(exitCode)
```

(Through these exit codes the python program tells the caller if everything succeeded. As you can see a variety of exit codes is used in order to allow a bit of error diagnosis on failure.)

So far so good. Basically this works. But what I do not understand is that sometimes my python program gives additional ouput like this:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method BufferedFile.__del__ of <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (closed) ->     <paramiko.Transport at 0x74300588 (unconnected)>>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 61, in __del__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 79, in close
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 88, in flush
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Or like this:

```
Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 61, in __del__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 79, in close
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 88, in flush
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Everything works fine all the time, but at about 10% to 20% of the time I see these error messages. Has anyone an idea why sometimes the cleanup fails on program termination? How can I avoid these error messages?

Comment: Which version of paramiko do you use, exactly?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I'm working on a pretty new Ubuntu 16.04 installation here. Strangely paramiko 1.17.0 was installed. Nevertheless an upgrade to the most recent version of paramiko - version 2.0.0 - did not change anything. Even the line numbers of the error messages remained the same. I just upgraded via pip3 and tested it with version 2.0.0 to no avail.

Comment: This is very likely a paramiko bug. You should write a bug report. Also, you should make sure that every "file" opened by `chan.makefile()` is `close()`d. Although this alone is unlikely to fix the problem, it will make sure no data is lost in the presence of this bug.

Comment: Hm. You really think it is a bug? Considering that there are probably millions of people using paramiko I didn't think of it that way.

Comment: Looking at line 88 of `paramiko/file.py`, the only object which is called is `BytesIO`. The only way this can "suddenly" become `None` is garbage collection at interpreter shutdown (unless someone explicitly sets it `None` somewhere, which is unlikely).

Comment: Regarding the new paramiko version: I just saw that the version 2.0.0 is just two days old. No wonder that my installation still contained the old version.

Comment: @manuel: Yes. This would support the assumption, that either (a) paramiko is not properly closing some I/O channels or (b) I am using the paramiko implementation somehow in a wrong way and need to do something more for a proper disconnect.

Answer (score 13):

For some reason, the garbage is not cleaned up automatically when sys.exit

To force the cleapup manually you can simply delete your allocated objected with **del**.

This is my code:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host, port, username, password)
stdin_raw, stdout_raw, stderr_raw = client.exec_command(cmd)
exit_code = stdout_raw.channel.recv_exit_status() 

stdout = []
for line in stdout_raw:
    stdout.append(line.strip())

stderr = []
for line in stderr_raw:
    stderr.append(line.strip())


# Clean up elements
client.close()
del client, stdin_raw, stdout_raw, stderr_raw


logger.debug("stdout: %s" % stdout)
logger.debug("stderr: %s" % stderr)
logger.debug("exit_code: %s" % exit_code)
```

Please mind the line:

```
del client, stdin_raw, stdout_raw, stderr_raw
```

This is my source:
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1078#issuecomment-596771584

Answer (score 3):

I ran exactly into the same problem (did not find your question at first, opened mine, now deleted). If you do not exit with `sys.exit`, you should not see the error anymore. What I did in my case was wrap the calls to paramiko and such in a function, so that `sys.exit` is not called in the same scope. In your case you could do:

```
def my_func(host, port, login, password, myCommand)
    exitCode = 0
    s = None
    try:
        ....
        exitCode = 3
        s = MySSHClient()
        s.connect(host, port, login, password)
        exitCode = 4
        result = s.exec_command(myCommand)
        exitCode = 5
        if not result.isSuccess():
            raise Exception("Failed to execute command!")
        exitCode = 0
    except:
        pass
    if s is not None:
        s.close()
    return exitCode

exit_code = my_func(my_host, my_port, my_login, my_password, my_command)
sys.exit(exit_code)
```

And it should work !

Comment: Thank you for experimenting! But I'm wondering: What difference does that make? It would suggest that there is something wrong with cleaning up Paramico if exit() is called? What's your opinion about this?

Comment: My limited understanding of the problem is that there is a garbage collection problem. `sys.exit` works by raising an exception so that statements in `finally` blocks are executed. My guess is an internal object is probably destroyed *sometimes* by garbage collector *before* it is called somewhere in a `finally` in paramiko, whereas when calling it from a function, the object must live on until the function returns.

Comment: I have opened a [ticket](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1078) on the paramiko github if you're interested.

Comment: If you invoke sys.exit() it really seems to raise that error. Hm. I now need to completely restructure my application in order to avoid that error :-/

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am unable to give you a better solution than this workaround, since the problem seems to stem from an internal paramiko misdesign.

Comment: Thank you for addressing it. I'm in the process of checking if I can live with this solution. I redesigned my application but I can get back to that project not immediately but in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you. I found that there was a `'\n'` at the end of my command string when I using `exec_command(command)`. I delete the `'\n'` and it works. The `exec_command` can execute a series of commands if you use `'\n'` to separate it. So i think the last `'\n'` start a new object but it is none inside so cause that None Type error.