# python2.4 library for SSH implementation

Tags: python, ssh, python-2.4

I am trying to implement SSH in python. But the python version installed is python2.4 which I can not update.

Is there any built-in module which works with python2.4? Or which module can I install for python2.4?

Comment: Do none of these suggestions work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python

Comment: Please check this out if it helps - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework-sshlibrary

Comment: I'm not a pythonista but I am sure there are a lot examples/answers out there.

Comment: I tried installing Paramiko but was leading into so many other errors which eventually couldn't resolve. Is there any other library which supports SSH with python2.4?

Comment: All solutions do not work over python 2.4. I keep seeking too. I got a lot of trouble to solve this and can not update production version too