# How do I shutdown my linux based computer remotely?

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I have absolutely basic knowledge regarding networking. And I know about ssh tunneling or connections but I have no clue how to apply it or use it. I'm designing an application for security and I need help getting past this hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user on the server you need to shutdown, that has rights to perform the action. Then add a key-pair, so your client can access this account without a password to perform the actual shutdown.

Now you can shutdown over ssh. The basic method to do this, is:

```
ssh -t <options> <user>@<hostname> sudo poweroff
```

([via](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251148/shutdown-over-ssh))

It looks like you want to do this in a python program, so now you need to call this via python. A simple way is this

```
   commands.getstatusoutput("ssh machine 1 'your script'")
```

([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python) note, there are more options in that question, and more questions about it to be found)

Answer (score 1):

I composed a command to suspend or shutdown a remote host over ssh. This may be used to suspend / shutdown a remote computer without an interactive session and yet not keep a terminal busy. You will need to give permissions to the remote user to shutdown / suspend using `sudo` without a password. Additionally, the local and remote machines should be set up to SSH without an interactive login. The script is more useful for suspending the machine as a suspended machine will not disconnect the terminal.

```
local_user@hostname:~$ ssh remote_user@remote_host "screen -d -m sudo pm-suspend"
```

source: [कार्यशाला (Kāryaśālā)](https://bharath.lohray.com/weblog/suspending-a-computer-over-ssh/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a tcp server on one machine and tcp client on another machine.

Send the string "shutdown" from the client to the server.

Write the tcp server in such a way that it shuts down the machine when it gets the string "shutdown".