# a way to execute commands over ssh with python with standard packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to find a way to execute commands with `python` over `ssh`. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586168/1636521), however I'm working on an embedded platform and can't install new packages. In other words I can't install [`paramiko`](http://www.paramiko.org/). Is there a way to do what [`paramiko`](http://www.paramiko.org/) does but with standard packages?

Comment: I would love to see an answer for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Unix based system with an ssh client? If so, could you use subprocess, https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html, to spawn another process and run ssh commands?

If not, have you tried to see if you can package paramiko itself with your code and deploy everything together to the target system? I'm not sure if this works, but it may be worth a shot.

Comment: I need the code to be OS neutral. Part of the reason is that testing will be done on a `Windows` machine but the final code will run on a `Linux` based system.

Comment: @flashburn Unfortunately that makes it more difficult as you're going to need an ssh client that works on both platforms, which I haven't seen before. Often time the packages for a client, library, program, etc, are built per platform.