# How to run multiple commands after login with ssh in python?

Tags: python, shell, ssh, subprocess, command

I want to execute some sequence of ssh commands through python script like below, (and want to display the output of the last command)

```
ssh hostname
sudo su userdb
cd /some/path/
./script_file -D option
```

I have tried with subprocess.Popen(each_command_from_list).

But it is getting stuck after connecting to hostname with ssh.

```
import subprocess

commands = ["ssh hostname", "sudo su userdb", "cd /some/path/", "./script_file -D option"]

for cmd in commands:
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
    if cmd.startswith("./script_file"):
        print(proc_stdout)
```

I expect, script should connect to hostname with ssh, and then run the commands in that host, and should get the results.

Answer (score -3):

Recommend you use some sort of wrapper like [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) to do this.

Example usage -- [Perform commands over ssh with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python)

Comment: Thank you for the response. As mentioned in my question, I have to execute commands.     

Using Paramiko, have connected to ssh host and executed commands, like
     ssh.connect('hostname')
ssh.exec_command('sudo su userdb')
inp, outp, err = ssh.exec_command('/some/path/script_file -D option')
      

But for the last command execution, I'm getting the permission error.
    
I don't think that 'sudo su userdb' command result persists with the next command execution which may cause the permission issue.
    
Any idea on this?

Comment: Why not just do it in a single line? `sudo su userdb && cd /some/path && ./script`