# How to change the value of a web page element using python (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, web, data-extraction

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="2020-01-23 23:59">
```

I want to change the value (2020-01-23 23:59) to (2020-01-01 23:59). Here the code I wrote, it is indeed changing the date on like the frontend so when I look at the webpage the date has changed. However, when I look at the Html file it is still the previous date. How can I change the date to whatever date I want and so that change is applied in the backend of the website.

(my code)

```
time.sleep(2)
startTime = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/input')
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", startTime, "2020-01-01 00:00")
endTime = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/input')
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", endTime, "2020-01-01 23:59")
time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Is the traditional `send_keys` not working for you here? You might need to click on a field outside of the `input` to trigger some sort of `onBlur()` event that saves the new date in the backend. It's hard to tell without seeing the website.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do? It seems like you want to modify an HTML file, it really isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium will only update the html inside the browser. It won't make any changes to the html file on the server. The world would be in trouble if it could.

I you want python to connect to the server, and you have credentials it is possible with something paramiko.
[Perform commands over ssh with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python)