# python subprocess output redirection

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, stdout

I'm working on a python script that `ssh` into a server and read some file contents. Let's say they are file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt.

For now I'm doing

```
commands = "ssh {host} {port}; cat file1.txt; cat file2.txt; cat file3.txt"

p = subprocess.run(commands, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

But this gives contents of three files concatenated. Is there some way that I can redirect each command's output to different pipe, so that I can easily distinguish which output came from which file?

Answer (score 1):

When using `subprocess` the way you did, you are executing the commands in sequence and in a batch, while grabbing the stdout. My suggestion would be to run them one by one, e.g.:

```
command1 = "ssh {host} {port}; cat file1.txt"
command1 = "ssh {host} {port}; cat file2.txt"
command1 = "ssh {host} {port}; cat file3.txt"

commands = [command1, command2, command3]

for cmd in commands:
     p = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
     # DO SOMETHING ABOUT THE OUTPUT OR IN BETWEEN OUTPUTS
```

You could also establish an `SSH` connection and send commands one by one instead of logging in each time. For that I suggest that you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python).

Comment: @SEUNGWON LEE: Could you please review the answer and consider accepting it (using the gray tick mark at the left on the answer)?