# Returning status of grep command executed remotely via ssh embedded in expect command inside python

Tags: python, ssh, expect

I have a below python script where in I am executing a remote SSH command using **expect**. Here, even the target file contains the string "*error*" or not, the exit code is returned as success always as the **ssh** connectivity is what only checked. How can I get the status of the **grep** command?

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import subprocess

def execute(cmd):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    _output, _error = proc.communicate()
    _code = proc.returncode
    return _output, _error, _code

host = "localhost"
passwd = "kube"

cmd="/usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn ssh "+host+" \"cat /home/kube/f1 | grep -qi error\"; expect \"password:\" { send \""+passwd+"\r\"} ;interact' "
_output, _error, return_code = execute(cmd)
print cmd + "\n" + _output + "\n" + _error

if (return_code == 0):
    print "no error"
else:
    print "contains error"
```

Comment: And what do you have in `_output` and `_error` after running this?

Comment: There are specialized libraries which are made for remote subprocess over SSH.  [paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python), or I use [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) to do this.  Also, password and ssh is missing the point of ssh somewhat, IMHO.

Comment: `zvone` no error only output `spawn ssh localhost cat /home/kube/f1 | grep -qi error
kube@localhost's password:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1:

Let the remote command output something which indicates success/failure for you. E.g.:

```
ssh user@host "/some/command | grep -q some-string && echo MAGIC-SUCCESS || echo MAGIC-FAILURE"
```

And in Python you can get the output and parse it.

#### Option 2:

According to `man expect`:

> - wait [args]
>
>   [...] `wait` normally returns a list of **four integers**.  The **first** integer is the  pid  of  the  process that  was waited upon.  The **second** integer is the corresponding spawn id.  The **third** integer is `-1` if an operating system error occurred, or `0` otherwise.  If the  **third**  integer  was  `0`,  the **fourth** integer is the status returned by the spawned process.  If the **third** integer was `-1`, the **fourth** integer is the value of `errno` set by the operating system. [...]

So your Expect code can check the `wait` result and then `exit` with different values and Python code can get the exit status.

For Expect part it's like this:

```
spawn ...
...
expect eof
set result [wait]
exit [lindex $result 3]
```

Comment: I added those lines in my `expect` command string `cmd="/usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn ssh "+host+" \"cat /home/kube/f1 | grep -qi error\"; expect \"password:\" { send \""+passwd+"\r\"} ;expect eof; set result [wait]; exit [lindex result 3]' "` but it always returns 0 (whether error string present or unavailable)

Comment: there was typo. just fixed. `lindex result 3` ==> `lindex $result 3`

Comment: by the way python has its own [tag:pexpect]. may be a bit easier than running Expect in python.