# What is the best way to ssh servers from django app?

Tags: django

I'm new to django and trying to build tool that need to perform task on linux servers.

I gone through Fabric which is cool, is this the only way i can do ssh?

When user submit request, the task/job should run background, what is the best way to achieve?

Appreciate for your all inputs suggestions.

Comment: Paramiko for SSH connections, Huey for doing them in the background (you don't want to do long operations during requests).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python