# Stop cmd windows from closing after running a . py file using PuTTY (Plink)

Tags: cmd, putty, plink

I have a Python script which is called to download certain data from database. I have a download button, when pressed a `cmd` window uses `Plink` opens up and show the progress and status inside this `cmd` window. After sometime the `cmd` window closes off very quickly automatically. How to stop it from closing (want this `cmd` window to be open until we close it) so that we can see the current status of download operation.

Answer (score 0):

Run *something* in the console window that pauses at the end.

Most trivial approach is to replace the direct `plink` call with `cmd` call that runs `plink` **and `pause`**:

```
cmd /c plink user@host command & pause
```

---

For ultimate control, do run your own Python script in the new console window. That way you can implement any kind of pause you want. You can even replace the `plink` call with native SSH Python code:
[Perform commands over ssh with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3586106/850848)