# How can i make a python script automatically enter a password?

Tags: python

So I am trying to write a script to automatically log into a server.
For the server I am using SHH.

```
import os

os.system("ssh root@address")
```

So when you enter the command manually you then get asked to enter the password and I don't know how to make the script enter the password.
Can someone help me out here?

I tried using the same command i used before, os.system(), but that enters a new command and stops the session. I just don't know the command to kinda answer to an output.

Comment: you should check the `subprocess` module, and do more research, i am sure this is answered elsewhere.

Comment: If you were able to enter a password, what then?  Are you expecting to enter commands into the ssh session?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do so. I wouldn't hardcode your password into the script for the sake of security but as long as you are sure only you are using the script it should be fine. This sample code is not trying to make it secure. I am just answering your question based on the constrains you gave.

If you insist on using `os.system` I would propose the following:

```
# change these 2 lines before
# ideally, opt to use environmental variables instead
PASSWORD="your password"
SSH_ADDRESS="name@ip"

os.system(f"""
/usr/bin/env expect <<EOF
spawn ssh {SSH_ADDRESS}
expect "{SSH_ADDRESS}'s password:"
send "{PASSWORD}\r"
interact
EOF
""")
```

This will be using the `expect` [command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) that lets you automate providing answers to to commands. One of the assumptions is that you have `expect` installed on your machine. If not, you will have to do so before attempting to make this work.
Still, I wouldn't encourage you to do so and instead use some package to connect to your server instead. I think it is better to avoid mixing shell commands inside the Python script if you have alternatives.

For instance, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python) and the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) that might be helpful for you. In the latter case, you will not even have to install anything extra on your machine