# ssh then execute a few cmds in remote linux machine from python

Tags: python, bash, ssh

I need to ssh to a remote machine and then execute a few cmds using python 3+.

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57439663/2175783 I tried

```
cmds = "cmd1; ./script.sh"
output, errors = subprocess.Popen(f'ssh user@{ip} {cmds}', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

where `script.sh` is a bash script.

But only `cmd1` seems to execute (I dont see output from `script.sh` only output from `cmd1`)

Anything obviously wrong?

Comment: Consider https://www.paramiko.org/

Comment: @kichik Unfortunately I can not add new libraries.

Comment: Look at the ssh man page: It is `ssh DESTINATION COMMAND`. You can pass only one command, but you try to pass two ( `cmd1` and `script.sh`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first cmd (cmd1) creates a shell in which the second script should run, I have found the following approach works

1. Create a second wrapper script called `wrapper_script.sh` containing both cmds

> ```
> cmd1<<EOF
> /path/to/script.sh
> EOF
> ```

2. Run the wrapper script

> ```
> import subprocess
> cmds = "'wrapper_script.sh'"
> output, errors = subprocess.Popen(f'ssh user@{ip} {cmds}', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
> print(output)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `./script.sh` is executed locally, not remotely, try this (notice the single quotes inside double quotes of `cmds`):

```
python << EOF
import subprocess
cmds = "'echo Hello; hostname'"
output, errors = subprocess.Popen(f'ssh user@{ip} {cmds}', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print(output)
EOF
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to make a difference. I think the issue is that the first cmd sets an environment [sets some env vars, enables a python virtual env, etc] in which the script (the second command) then should run.

Comment: Then there must be other errors, Add `print(errors)` at the end of above python script, and see what's wrong.

Comment: A command can only set the environment for children, so once the first command finishes, everything is the same as before

Answer (score 1):

You should use [fabric](https://docs.fabfile.org/) and do something like

```
with Connection(host=ip, user=user) as c:
   c.run('command1')
   c.run('command2')
```

Answer (score 1):

At least part of the problem is that the local shell (invoked by `shell=True`) is processing the command before it's sent to the remote system, so the `;` in the command string is treated as a command delimiter on the local system (and the part after `;` executes locally rather than being sent to the remote system). If the actual command is more complex, it may be doing other unwanted parsing (e.g. replacing `$variable` in the command with the *local* value of that variable).

At least in the example in the question, the local shell isn't doing anything useful, so one solution is to use `shell=True`. There is one other change, though: rather than passing the command as a single string, you need to pass it as a list of words, like `["ssh", f"user@{ip}", cmds]`:

```
output, errors = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", f"user@{ip}", cmds], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Avoiding expanding `$variable` references locally might solve the environment variable problems you're having; if not, you'd have to explain how you're defining and using the variables in question.