# SSH python script execution taking too much time

Tags: python, ssh

I am using python script to ssh and connect two pc's for running iperf commands, but the script is taking a lot of time for execution. How can I reduce the execution time: the script is being run from eclipse IDE.

this is the script that i am using:

```
import pexpect
import pxssh
import time
import os,re,sys



def tc01s(ipaddr,password):
try:

    ss = pexpect.spawn(ipaddr)
    print ipaddr    
        ss.logfile = open("/tmp/mynewlog", "w")
        #ss.logfile = sys.stdout
        print "SSH connecting"
        print 
except:
    print "connection refused"
    print
    #sys.exit()

    try:
        print password
    ss.expect (':')


        ss.sendline (password +"\n")
        print "connected"
        time.sleep(30)
        ss.expect (">")
        print "connection established"
        print
    except:
        print "Permission denied, please try again."
        print
        sys.exit()
    try:
        ss.sendline ('taskkill /F /IM iperf.exe\n')
        #time.sleep(30)
        ss.expect ('>')
        #os.system("D:\iperf-2.0.5-2-win32\iperf.exe -s\n")
        ss.sendline ('cd /D D:\iperf-2.0.5-2-win32')
        ss.expect ('>')
        ss.sendline ('iperf -s -u -f m -p 5000 -l 1470 -i 1')
        ss.expect (r'TCP window size: .*yte \(default\)')
        time.sleep(30)                
    except: 
        print 
        print
        #sys.exit()


###############################################################################
time.sleep(30)
def tc01c(ipaddr,password):

try:
    css = pexpect.spawn(ipaddr)
    css.logfile = open("/tmp/mynewlog", "w")
    #css.logfile = (sys.stdout)
    print "SSH connecting"
    print
except:
    print "connection refused"
    print
    sys.exit()
try:
    css.expect (':')
    css.sendline (password + "\n")
    print "connected"
    time.sleep(30)
    css.expect (">")
    print "connection established"
    print
except:
    print "Permission denied, please try again."
    print
    sys.exit()
try:
    #css.sendline ('taskkill /F /IM iperf.exe\n')
    print css.logfile
    css.expect ('>')
    css.sendline ('D:' + "\r")
    #css.sendline ('cd /D D:\iperf-2.0.5-2-win32')
    css.expect ('>')
    css.sendline ('dir' + "\r")
    css.sendline ('cd iperf ' + "\r")
    css.expect ('>')
    css.sendline ('iperf -u -f m -c 192.168.100.101 -p 5000 -b 3.00M -t 10 -l 1470 -i 1 \r\n')
    css.expect (r'TCP window size: .*yte \(default\)')          
    time.sleep(30)


except: 
    print 
    print
    #sys.exit() 

###############################################
the above code is executed using 
import os
import pexpect
import ssh
import time

ssh.tc01s("ssh user@192.168.100.101","pass123")
ssh.tc01c("ssh domain@192.168.100.85","123pass")
```

Comment: i believe Eclipse is making it slow. Try running outside Eclipse.

Comment: We need to see the script to advise.

Comment: can you go over the formatting again? Also, what is 'a long time'? There's a bunch of `time.sleep`

Answer (score 1):

As commenters mentioned, without the code this could be really hard to answer. But in case you don't want/can't attach the code here, I would have some guesses:

- If you're running an executable SSH client, try switching to a [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939107/python-libraries-for-ssh-handling).
- Maybe the specific commands you're running is what's slow, and not the connection itself? Try running something else (simpler) to know for sure that the SSH connection is what's slow.
- Other wild guesses of things that might slow you down: Network is slow, receiving ends are busy, your host is busy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If it is taking a long time for establishing the connection, you might want to disable the UseDNS option in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config of both the machines.